# Discordjs 14 failing in my existing typescript bot project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I have updated my discordjs from 12 to 14.
I faced other issues as well but reinstalling those library fixed the issues and I tried the same for discord-akairo but it didn't work.

Error

```
node_modules/discord-akairo/src/index.d.ts:4:18 - error TS2305: Module '"discord.js"' has no exported member 'MessageAttachment'.

4         Message, MessageAttachment, MessageEmbed,
```

I am facing in total 6 errors

```
    node_modules/discord-akairo/src/index.d.ts:4:37 - error TS2305: Module '"discord.js"' has no exported member 'MessageEmbed'.
    
    4         Message, MessageAttachment, MessageEmbed,
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    node_modules/discord-akairo/src/index.d.ts:5:9 - error TS2724: '"discord.js"' has no exported member named 'MessageAdditions'. Did you mean 'MessageEditOptions'?
    
    5         MessageAdditions, MessageEditOptions, MessageOptions, SplitOptions,
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    node_modules/discord-akairo/src/index.d.ts:5:47 - error TS2724: '"discord.js"' has no exported member named 'MessageOptions'. Did you mean 'BaseMessageOptions'?
    
    5         MessageAdditions, MessageEditOptions, MessageOptions, SplitOptions,
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    node_modules/discord-akairo/src/index.d.ts:5:63 - error TS2305: Module '"discord.js"' has no exported member 'SplitOptions'.
    
    5         MessageAdditions, MessageEditOptions, MessageOptions, SplitOptions,
                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    node_modules/discord-akairo/src/index.d.ts:8:31 - error TS2724: '"discord.js"' has no exported member named 'StringResolvable'. Did you mean 'UserResolvable'?
    
    8         PermissionResolvable, StringResolvable, Snowflake
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    
    Found 6 errors in the same file, starting at: node_modules/discord-akairo/src/index.d.ts:4
```

discord-akairo -^8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Most of theses types have been renamed or deleted in discord.js v14.

> `MessageEmbed` has now been renamed to `EmbedBuilder`

You can check this [link](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#messageselectmenu) for complete migration actions (even if you are migrating from v12 to v14, you can still check [v12 to v13 guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start) but you won't really need it since it seems all v14 related).

Comment: MessageAdditions,StringResolvable,SplitOptions these are not found in the doc. How will i find the new term for these 3 terms.

Comment: Can you show me where you use them ? I bet you didn't need to explicitly use them anymore